# Testing a Promise that returns a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I have a function that looks like

```
const BypassSFTP = {
  execute: function(config, callback) {
    const sftp = new Client()
    sftp.connect(config)
      .then(() => {
        return sftp.list('./');
      })
      .then((fileList) => {
        console.log(fileList)
        return retrieveFileStreams.go(sftp, fileList, "sftp")
      })
      .then((fileStreams) => {
        console.log(fileStreams)
        return streamToString(fileStreams)
      })
})}
```

im stubbing it with sinon like

```
sinon.stub(Client.prototype, 'connect').callsFake(function(config) {
      return Q.when()
    });

    sinon.stub(Client.prototype, 'list').callsFake(function() {
      return Q.when('meow2')
    });

    sinon.stub(retrieveFileStreams, 'go').callsFake(function(a, b, c) {
      return Q.when('meow3')
    });
```

im doing some asserts like

```
bypassSFTP.execute(config, callback_2);
sinon.assert.calledOnce(Client.prototype.connect);
sinon.assert.calledOnce(Client.prototype.list);
sinon.assert.calledOnce(retrieveFileStreams.go);
```

Now the issue is that after the `Client.connect` call it does not recognize that the other function like `sftp.list()` are called

What would be the best way to test this?

Comment: _All_ A+ Promise handlers return a Promise

Comment: that is correct

Comment: I think `execute` will be returning undefined after the `connect` call. You need to `return sftp.connect(config)`.